# Is there a built-in way to swap two variables in C?

Tags: c

I know how to swap two variables in C++, ie you use `std::swap(a,b)`.

Does the C standard library have a similar function to C++'s `std::swap()`, or do I have to define it myself?

Comment: There's a newer question with an interesting answer not represented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982348/implement-generic-swap-macro-in-c

Comment: More answers (probably should be merged): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982348/implement-generic-swap-macro-in-c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no equivalent in C - in fact there can't be, as C doesn't have template functions. You will have to write separate functions for all the types you want to swap.

Comment: so c has no standard library algorithms? swapping is a commonly used feature

Comment: @Dr: C doesn't have a default data structure library.

Comment: @Dr Deo C doesn't have lots of things that C++ does - that's kind of the point.

Comment: Outside of writing your own sorting algorithm, what would it be needed for?  And C already has qsort().

Comment: @Ken actually, in C++ swap() is used in all sorts of "creative" ways! Most of which would not admittedly apply to C code.

Comment: Since this is often done in a macro, its not quite correct to say *"You will have to write separate functions for all the types you want to swap"*

Answer (score 25):

You need to define it yourself.

1. C doesn't have templates.
2. If such function does exist it would look like `void swap(void* a, void* b, size_t length)`, but unlike `std::swap`, it's not type-safe.
3. And there's no hint such function could be inlined, which is important if swapping is frequent (in C99 there's `inline` keyword).
4. We could also define a macro like

   ```
    #define SWAP(a,b,type) {type ttttttttt=a;a=b;b=ttttttttt;}
   ```

   but it shadows the `ttttttttt` variable, and you need to repeat the type of `a`. (In gcc there's `typeof(a)` to solve this, but you still cannot `SWAP(ttttttttt,anything_else);`.)
5. And writing a swap in place isn't that difficult either — it's just 3 simple lines of code!

Comment: To avoid shadowing `ttttttttt`, (or causing a bug if that variable is passed in as an argument). you can call the variable `SWAP` too.

Answer (score 14):

You can do something similar with a macro if you don't mind using a gcc extension to the C language, `typeof`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a, b) do { typeof(a) temp = a; a = b; b = temp; } while (0)

int main(void)
{
    int a = 4, b = 5;
    float x = 4.0f, y = 5.0f;
    char *p1 = "Hello";
    char *p2 = "World";

    SWAP(a, b); // swap two ints, a and b
    SWAP(x, y); // swap two floats, x and y
    SWAP(p1, p2); // swap two char * pointers, p1 and p2

    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    printf("x = %g, y = %g\n", x, y);
    printf("p1 = %s, p2 = %s\n", p1, p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation (portability aside) is that it will blindly swap anything, without regard to semantics (for example if dynamic memory allocation is involved). The C++ swap will call constructors and destructors appropriately to handle this. Downvote wasn't me, BTW.

Comment: @Neil: true, but the OP was specifically asking for a `C` implementation. It's far from a perfect solution, but it's a reasonable solution for a significant subset of C applications (IMNVHO).

Comment: You could implement this using C11's _generic expressions.

Comment: @CasperBeyer I don't see how that would work for `struct` types

Comment: If one is going to use a GCC extension, why not two?  :-)  Use a _statement expression_ instead of the _do while_.

Comment: @GregA.Woods: A statement-expression is only useful if you want to return a value.  The do{}while() idiom for macros is well-understood, and everyone knows that it's safe even when substituted into an `if (foo) SWAP() else ...` context.  I might have to stop and think about it if it was `({...; b = temp; })`.  It doesn't take much extra mental time to see that that's ok too, but it's non-zero and I don't see the benefit of having it evaluate to the final value of `b` (or `a`).

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `_tmp`, to make sure you don't have a problem when someone writes `int x=1, temp = 0;  SWAP(temp, x);`.  Or, as @ideasman42 pointed out on another answer, use SWAP as the tmp var name.  It won't expand inside the macro of the same name.  (That's more confusing to read, though.)  GNU C headers frequently use `_`-prefixed names for temporaries inside macros, since user code shouldn't be using those var names itself (It's ok to shadow globals of those names, only a problem if user code actually does `SWAP(_tmp, x)`).

Comment: I think you missed the point of, i.e. the benefit of, the more generic nature of using a _statement expression_ @PeterCordes.  They are usable even if they don't return a (useful/desired) value, and given the (ab)use of one language extension, the use another which, for all intents and purposes, always accompanies the first affords the additional flexibility at zero additional cost.  I would also argue a macro using a _statement expression_ is also far more readable in both its original form and also in the preprocessor output.

Comment: @GregA.Woods: I got that that was at least part of your point, and (slightly) disagreed with it.  `do{}while(0)` is a very standard idiom for macros, and is *more readable* since it's what I'd be looking for to make sure the macro was written in the usual safe way.  If I don't see that, I'd spend an extra second looking more closely to see what is going on.  If you have other macros that also use statement-expressions (like min and max), it would be very reasonable to use one for this, too, though.  Either way, I don't think I'd change it in an existing codebase, not worth the diff noise.

Comment: TL:DR: it's not just compiler support, it's about human reader support.  Not everyone is even familiar with the statement-expression extension.  (Although they should be, because they're great!)

Answer (score 9):

This works quickly in Clang and gcc (but not icc, which doesn't recognize this swap function - however, it will compile in any standard C99 compiler), provided that the optimizations actually recognize the swap (they do on high enough optimization levels).

```
#include <string.h>

#define SWAP(a, b) swap_internal(&(a), &(b), sizeof *(1 ? &(a) : &(b)))
static inline void swap_internal(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
    char tmp[size];
    memcpy(tmp, a, size);
    memmove(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, size);
}
```

Now for explaining how it works. First, the `SWAP()` line is relatively strange, but it's actually relatively simple. `&(a)` is argument `a` passed as a pointer. Similarly, `&(b)` is argument `b` passed as an pointer.

The most interesting piece of code is `sizeof *(1 ? &(a) : &(b))`. This is actually a relatively clever piece of error reporting. If error reporting wouldn't be needed, it could be just `sizeof(a)`. Ternary operator requires that its operations have compatible types. In this case, I check two different arguments for their type compatibility by converting them to pointer (otherwise, `int` and `double` would be compatible). As `int *` and `double *` aren't compatible, compilation would fail... provided it's standard C compiler. Sadly, many compilers assume `void *` type in this case, so it fails, but at least with a warning (that is enabled by default). To ensure correct size of the result, the value is dereferenced, and applied to `sizeof`, so there are no sideeffects.

```
~/c/swap $ gcc swap.c
swap.c: In function ‘main’:
swap.c:5:64: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]
 #define SWAP(a, b) swap_internal(&(a), &(b), sizeof *(1 ? &(a) : &(b)))
                                                                ^
swap.c:16:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWAP’
     SWAP(cat, dog);
     ^
~/c/swap $ clang swap.c
swap.c:16:5: warning: pointer type mismatch ('int *' and 'double *') [-Wpointer-type-mismatch]
    SWAP(cat, dog);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
swap.c:5:57: note: expanded from macro 'SWAP'
#define SWAP(a, b) swap_internal(&(a), &(b), sizeof *(1 ? &(a) : &(b)))
                                                        ^ ~~~~   ~~~~
1 warning generated.
~/c/swap $ icc swap.c
swap.c(16): warning #42: operand types are incompatible ("int *" and "double *")
      SWAP(cat, dog);
      ^
```

This macro evaluates everything exactly once (`sizeof` is special, as it doesn't evaluate its arguments). This provides safety against arguments like `array[something()]`. The only limitation I can think of is that it doesn't work on `register` variables because it depends on pointers, but other than that, it's generic - you can even use it for variable length arrays. It can even handle swapping identical variables - not that you would want to do that.

Comment: This will probably defeat some optimizations in most compilers.  Many are pretty good at seeing through this kind of use of memcpy, but definitely not perfect.  I would highly recommend not using this if you care about performance.  At best this might make an `#ifdef` fallback for compilers that don't support GNU extensions, specifically `typeof()`.

Comment: Another option for implementing `swap_internal`, although not very efficient, is to do the swap a byte at a time: `static inline void swap_internal(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {` `char *x = a;` `char *y = b;` `char t;` `while (size--) {` `t = *x;` `*x++ = *y;` `*y++ = t;` `}` `}`. It may be useful if VLAs are not supported or if memory is tight.

Answer (score 3):

In C this is often done using a macro,
there are very simplistic examples, eg:
`#define SWAP(type,a,b) {type _tmp=a;a=b;b=_tmp;}`
... but I wouldn't recommend using them because they have some non-obvious flaws.

This is a macro written to avoid accidental errors.

```
#define SWAP(type, a_, b_) \
do { \
    struct { type *a; type *b; type t; } SWAP; \
    SWAP.a  = &(a_); \
    SWAP.b  = &(b_); \
    SWAP.t  = *SWAP.a; \
    *SWAP.a = *SWAP.b; \
    *SWAP.b =  SWAP.t; \
} while (0)
```

- Each argument is instantiated only once,
  so `SWAP(a[i++], b[j++])` doesn't give problem side effects.
- temp variable name is also `SWAP`, so as not to cause bugs if a different name happens to collide with the hard-coded name chosen.
- It doesn't call `memcpy` (which in fact ended up doing real function calls in my tests, even though a compiler may optimize them out).
- Its type-checked
  (comparing as pointers makes the compiler warn if they don't match).

Comment: You're using a struct instead of three separate variables since SWAP is the only name it's absolutely guaranteed to be safe to use, right?  (So you can only have one variable).  Another option is to use things like `_a`, `_b`, and `_tmp`, since code using your macro should not be touching any _prefixed variables.  It's ok to shadow a global called `_a` inside your macro, since no use of the macro should involve `SWAP(_a, x)`.  But your way avoids this source of breakage even in bad programs that use reserved names for their own vars.

Comment: Right, and some projects use `-Wshadow` so it's nice to be able to rule this out even as an unlikely possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Check your compiler documentation.  The compiler may have a `swapb` function for swapping bytes and my provide other similar functions.

Worst case, waste a day and write some generic swap functions.  It won't consume a significant amount of your project's schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which is arguably better than anything proposed so far:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

inline void memswap(void * restrict buffer, void *l, void *r, size_t size) {
    memcpy(buffer, l, size);
    memmove(l, r, size);
    memcpy(r, buffer, size);
}

#define swap(a, b) \
    memswap(&(struct {\
        _Static_assert(sizeof *(a) == sizeof *(b), "arguments of swap must have same size" ); \
        char _[sizeof*(a)];\
    }) {0}, (a), (b), sizeof*(a))


void example(int *x, int *y) {
    // produces same assembly instructions as
    //     int t = *x;
    //     *x = *y
    //     *y = t;
    swap(x, y);
}
```

The basic idea is that we make a compound literal with the same size as `*a` and pass this into a `memswap` helper function that swaps `l` and `r` with the help of the `b` buffer.
The compound literal also contains a `_Static_assert` declaration which ensures that the size of `*a` is equal to the size of `*b`.

This solution has many advantages:

- it is safer because of the additional size test
- the macro expands to an expression, not a statement, like all the others
- it does not rely on VLAs, so it is more portable
- it does not declare any local variables
- [it produces optimal code](https://godbolt.org/z/K1bT9356E), at least for GCC and clang

Answer (score 0):

Another macro not already mentioned here: You don't need to give the type if you give the temporary variable instead. Additionally the comma operator is useful here to avoid the do-while(0) trick. But usually I don't care and simply write the three commands. On the other hand a temporary macro is useful if a and b are more complex.

```
#define SWAP(a,b,t) ((t)=(a), (a)=(b), (b)=(t))

void mix_the_array (....)
{
    int tmp;
    .....
    SWAP(pointer->array[counter+17], pointer->array[counter+20], tmp);
    .....
}

#undef SWAP
```

Answer (score 0):

in essence, swap function is to swap two memory block. with two addresses and the size of block in bytes, we can swap pointers, integers, doubles, arrays, structs, ...

a pointer has three parts, e.g. we can break down `short* p` into three pieces

1. address: void* p
2. size: reading two bytes at `void*p`, we get a short integer.
3. usage: e.g. print a short integer with `%hu`

using the first two parts, we will be able to build a generic swap function:

```
#include<stdint.h> 
#ifdef _WIN32
#define alloca _alloca
#else
#include <alloca.h>
#endif

void gswap(void * const a, void * const b, int const sz) {
    // for most case, 8 bytes will be sufficient.
    int64_t tmp; // equivalent to char tmp[8];
    void * p;
    bool needfree = false;
    if (sz > sizeof(int64_t)) {
        // if sz exceed 8 bytes, we allocate memory in stack with little cost.
        p = alloca(sz);
        if (p == NULL) {
            // if sz is too large to fit in stack, we fall back to use heap.
            p = malloc(sz);
            //assert(p != NULL, "not enough memory");
            needfree = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        p = &tmp;
    }

    memcpy(p, b, sz);
    memcpy(b, a, sz);
    memcpy(a, p, sz);

    if (needfree) {
        free(p);
    }

}
```

e.g.:

```
{// swap int 
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    printf("%d,%d\n", a, b);//3,4
    gswap(&a, &b, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d,%d\n", a, b);//4,3
}
{// swap int64
    int64_t a = 3;
    int64_t b = 4;
    printf("%lld,%lld\n", a, b);//3,4
    gswap(&a, &b, sizeof(int64_t));
    printf("%lld,%lld\n", a, b);//4,3
}
{// swap arrays
    int64_t a[2] = { 3,4 };
    int64_t b[2] = { 5,6 };
    printf("%lld,%lld,%lld,%lld\n", a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]);//3,4,5,6
    gswap(&a, &b, sizeof(a));
    printf("%lld,%lld,%lld,%lld\n", a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]);//5,6,3,4
}
{// swap arrays
    double a[2] = { 3.,4. };
    double b[2] = { 5.,6. };
    printf("%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]);//3.000000, 4.000000, 5.000000, 6.000000
    arrswap(&a, &b, sizeof(a));
    printf("%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]);//5.000000, 6.000000, 3.000000, 4.000000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the swapping mechanism involve -

```
//( Not quite good, try passing ++x and ++y as arguments :-} )
#define SWAP_0(x,y) { x = x+y; \
                      y = x-y; \
                      x = x-y; }

//Faster than SWAP_0
#define SWAP_1(x,y) { x ^= y; \
                      y ^= x; \
                      x ^= y; }

//Optimal for general usage
#define SWAP_2(x,y)                                                                         \
                 do                                                                         \
                {                                                                           \
                    uint8_t __temp[sizeof(x) == sizeof(y) ? (signed)sizeof(x) : -1];        \
                    memcpy(__temp,     &y, sizeof(x));                                      \
                    memcpy(    &y,     &x, sizeof(x));                                      \
                    memcpy(    &x, __temp, sizeof(x));                                      \
                } while(0)

//using GCC specific extension
#define SWAP_3(x, y) do                                                                     \
                    {                                                                       \
                        typeof(x) SWAP_3 = x; x = y; y = SWAP_3;                            \
                    }while (0)

//without GCC specific extension - can be invoked like this - SWAP_3(x,y, int) or SWAP_3(x,y, float)
#define SWAP_4(x, y, T) do                                                                  \
                    {                                                                       \
                        T SWAP_4 = x; x = y; y = SWAP_4;                                    \
                    }while (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is to take a size argument, and just swap the items one byte at a time

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

inline void swap_generic(void* const restrict l, void* const restrict r, const size_t size) {
    uint8_t* const left  = l;
    uint8_t* const right = r;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        uint8_t temp_byte = right[i];
        right[i]  = left[i];
        left[i]   = temp_byte;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following macro does this in a type-safe way and **works with different types**:

```
#include <memory.h>

#define SWAP(a, b) do { char tmp1[sizeof(a)], tmp2[sizeof(a)]; \
    memcpy(tmp1, &(a), sizeof(a)); \
    (a) = (b); \
    memcpy(tmp2, &(a), sizeof(a)); \
    memcpy(&(a), tmp1, sizeof(a)); \
    (b) = (a); \
    memcpy(&(a), tmp2, sizeof(a)); \
    } while(0)
```

This macro

1. first stores original value of `a` in the temp buffer `tmp1`
2. gets new value of `a` by assignment from `b`
3. stores the new value of `a` to the temp buffer `tmp2`
4. restores original value of `a` from `tmp1`
5. gets final value of `b` by assignment from `a`
6. finally restores the correct new value of `a` from `tmp2`

The [Godbolt.org compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Cmemory.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+SWAP(a,+b)+do+%7B+char+tmp1%5Bsizeof(a)%5D,+tmp2%5Bsizeof(a)%5D%3B+%5C%0A++++memcpy(tmp1,+%26(a),+sizeof(a))%3B+%5C%0A++++a+%3D+b%3B+%5C%0A++++memcpy(tmp2,+%26(a),+sizeof(a))%3B+%5C%0A++++memcpy(%26(a),+tmp1,+sizeof(a))%3B+%5C%0A++++b+%3D+a%3B+%5C%0A++++memcpy(%26(a),+tmp2,+sizeof(a))%3B+%5C%0A++++%7D+while(0)%0A++++%0A++++%0Avoid+test(char+*ap,+uint64_t+*bp)+%7B%0A++++SWAP(*ap,+*bp)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) demonstrates that at least GCC is able to optimize this nicely already at -O2.

Answer (score -1):

Lots of nice solutions in the other answers! Just another quick swap macro for C that I came up with when reading K&R:

```
#define SWAP(TYPE,x,y) TYPE a = x, x=y, y=a
```

Answer (score -4):

In case of numeric values (at least):

I know this is not an actual or complete answer but until now everyone has been making use of temporary variables so I thought [Chris Taylors blog](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/25/xor-trick/) might be relevant to mention, it certainly does remove the need for typeof() etc.

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

or

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

In theory I suppose these techniques could be applied to strings and other types as well..

Still only three operations.

Comment: Likely to be wrong for floating-point values, so not all 'numeric' types.  And the second may be UB for signed types (due to overflow).