# General swap method for primitive types

Tags: c#, objective-c

I've searched around but nothing useful for me founded.

What is the best way to write a swap method to exchange two primitive values in `ObjectiveC`?

You know the primitive types have different sizes, so if we pass them through something like `void *`, then how can we know about their size? (maybe one extra parameter for their size?)

in `C#`, it could be something like this :

```
void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    T tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

An idea could be creating a temp memory block with the same size of input types, then copying them as memory blocks with a method like `memcpy` or something.

But I prefer something more natural in `ObjectiveC`, if there is a better one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3982397/834998

Comment: Seems it's the best solution :) thank you...

Comment: Use Objective-C++ and employ `std::swap`.

Answer (score 0):

If the type is truly a primitive, you can use the XOR swap algorithm.

```
x = x ^ y;
y = x ^ y;
x = x ^ y;
```

In a macro, this could look as follows:

```
#define SWAP(a, b) (a^=b;b^=a;a^=b;)
```

But care should always be taken with macros.

Otherwise, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982430/2471910

Comment: Right - it won't work on pointers due to the compiler.  It will work on other data types of the same size (long for example).