# Swap any type of two variables in c

Tags: c, pointers, swap

Is there any logic in c which can swap any type of two variables. i.e int, float, sequence of character.

I can think of a logic of storing every type of variables as sequence of characte and swap it like normal string but i does not its good idea.

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? Its possible but difficult. Probably there is an eaiser way to accomplish what you are doing.

Comment: You want to write generic codes, good! learn about `void*` pointers

Comment: in `c` it's very hard to write any generic code, and it usually involves non type-safe casts (eg: void*), function pointers or ugly macros. check `c++`.

Comment: Yes just swap values of pointers. Use generic void* pointers

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: not a duplicate, not generic.

Comment: Read [Paul R's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3982397/1673391)

Comment: @gbtimon what is the easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how you'd do this for two `char` variables. You'd do something like this.

```
void swap(char* a, char* b)
{
    char tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

For two `int` variables:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

And so on. Now, for catering to *any* type of variable, you'd be tempted to do:

```
void swap(void* a, void* b)
{
    // ...
}
```

But you'd need to allocate a space of a parameterized size. So, you'll have to first receive that size as a parameter:

```
void swap(void* a, void* b, size_t s)
{
    // ...
}
```

...which you'll pass as an argument using a `sizeof` expression. And you'll need to allocate said space and do assignments (copies) using that. Off the top of my head, `malloc`/`free` and `memcpy` come to mind, so a crude way to do what we did above for `char` and `int`, but this time with a parameterized size, would be:

```
void swap_any(void* a, void* b, size_t s){
    void* tmp = malloc(s);
    memcpy(tmp, a, s);
    memcpy(a, b, s);
    memcpy(b, tmp, s);
    free(tmp);
}
```

As I described, this is a little crude. You could try doing it with `alloca` (which allocates on the stack) and no `free`.

Alternatively, you could do it with a macro, since you can pass a *type* (instead of a `size_t`) to a macro - because macros essentially work using text replacement. Then, you can obviously create the temporary variable type by name, like this:

```
#define swap_m(a, b, t) { t tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }
```

Obviously, if you don't want to pass any information at all about the involved types, you'd have to be more creative about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro for that, but it won't work for everything:

```
#define SWAP(a,b) { __typeof__(a) temp; temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }
```

Comment: That is a gcc extension.

Comment: Even if you consider that `__typeof__` works correctly, it might be better to write it as `#define SWAP(a,b) do {...} while(0)`. Your code may behave incorrectly in some cases. For example, `if (flag) SWAP(a, b); else printf("No swap call performed")`. This code will not compile.