# Is it safe to assume memcpy fixed size is optimzied out?

Tags: c, optimization

Using GCC you can do something like this.

```
void foo(MyStruct *a, const MyStruct *b)
{
    memcpy(&a[0], b, sizeof(*a));
    memcpy(&a[1], b, sizeof(*a));
    memcpy(&a[2], b, sizeof(*a));
}
```

When writing portable code, using modern C compilers *, this can optimize to output the same `asm` as ...

```
void foo(MyStruct a[3], const MyStruct *b)
{
    a[0] = *b;
    a[1] = *b;
    a[2] = *b;
}
```

---

My question is, is it reasonable to assume the function call to `memcpy` will *always* be be optimized out?

*I'm asking this because I was considering to use `memcpy` in a macro which gets instantiated many times with size known at compile time. If this will call `memcpy` on some platforms, I'd prefer to avoid calling it at all.*
eg: [Implement generic swap macro in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982348/implement-generic-swap-macro-in-c/3982430#3982430)

---

* *modern C compilers (GCC/Clang/MSVC/ICC). with standard/safe optimization level set.*

Comment: Uh, why don't you just write `a[0] = *b;` etc. in the function/macro

Comment: In the example given, sure- but this swap macro for example uses `memcpy`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3982430/432509 - knowing if this is something to be avoided or not is useful.

Comment: You can still assign an array by-value if it's wrapped inside a struct. (might help, might not)

Comment: @Leushenko, yep, I was looking into using a temp struct to use assignment, not sure if `struct` padding could bite me here though. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192256

Answer (score 3):

Some naive C compilers (like [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git)) don't optimize much and won't optimize calls to `memcpy`; but they produce so slow code that nobody careing about binary code performance would use them.

<sup>However, a good reason to use `tcc`  might be when you don't care at all about runtime performance, but you care a lot about having a *tiny* compiler able to compile *quickly*</sup>

In theory, [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) is not mandated by the [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard (even a real or virtual computer is not required: you could run a standard C program with a bunch of human slaves, but that is unethical, unreliable, and inefficient). And the C99 standard does not *require* a compiler; it could be a naive interpreter and still be a standard conforming implementation.

In practice, any serious C compiler, when asked to optimize, would optimize your calls to `memcpy`

See also [this answer on *Programmers*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065).

So I would use `memcpy` like you do, but document that a modern C *optimizing* compiler is expected (and perhaps *recommend* recent *versions* of compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.8 at least, or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) 3.4 at least)

Answer (score 0):

The `memcpy` function is a very broad function that takes `void *` parameters as its inputs.

From ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99):

Synopsis:

> void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);

Description:

> The **memcpy** function copies n characters from the object pointed to by **s2** into the object pointed to by **s1**. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

As you can see, the description is quite vague as to what optimizations are allowed to be placed on it. However, the function prototype does use the keyword `restrict` allowing optimizing compilers to recognize the two as distinct memory regions.

But again from §6.7.3.1 Formal definition of restrict:

> A translator is free to ignore any or all aliasing implications of uses of restrict.

Suggesting that perhaps not all optimizing compilers recognize the flag directly. In this case, memcpy would be working on (from the compiler's perspective) possible duplicate/overlapping memory regions and be unable to make the deduction of functional equivalence to `a[0] = *b` since that may be modifying the value of `b` as well.

Standards may have changed in C11 but I don't a copy of that so I can't say...

Edit:

The N1570 draft has the same thing written for both sections so it should be the same, though I haven't read the whole thing to make sure of this.

Comment: The [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is very nearly identical to the C11 standard.