# Swap function in Function-Like Macros

Tags: c

Go through the following C code

```
# define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
main( )
{
    int i, j, temp;
    i=5;
    j=10;
    temp=0;
    if( i > j)
        swap ( i, j );
    printf ( "%d %d %d", i, j, temp);
}
```

Compiler Output:

```
10 0 0
```

I am Expecting this output

```
10 5 0
```

Why am I wrong??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the lack of braces. This is one of the common pitfalls with macros. Let's see what happens:

```
if(i > j)
    swap(i, j);
```

becomes:

```
if(i > j)
    temp = a; a = b; b = temp;;
```

Made a little more readable:

```
if(i > j)
    temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

So the lines `a = b;` and `b = temp;` will always be executed, they fall outside the `if` body.

Either put braces around the `if`, or the macro.

Answer (score 5):

It is much better to define statement-like macros with a `do{`...`}while(0)` like (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/841108)):

```
#define swap(a,b) do { int temp=a; a=b; b=temp; } while(0)
```

since the `do{`....`}while(0)` construct is correctly understood (even as the *then* or `else` part of a conditional, etc. etc... as explained in other replies.

Actually, you'll still have issues if you invoke `swap` with a `temp` argument (e.g. `swap(temp,xx)`) or if you use it with a side effecting second argument (e.g. `swap(x,y++)` would increment `y` twice and not do what you want).

A pedantically robust `swap` might use [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) at preprocessing level and some unique counter like the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) specific [`__COUNTER__` predefined macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) to generate a unique symbol (instead of `temp`)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the if condition in this line:

```
if( i > j)
swap ( i, j );
```

After the preprocessor has replaced your define, these lines look like the following:

```
if( i > j)
temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
```

What you expect is the following:

```
if( i > j)
{temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

which can be achieved by changing your define to

```
#define swap(a,b) {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by others, a more robust solution would be to define the macro as

```
#define swap(a,b) do{temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}while(1)
```

This still requires the variable `temp` to be declared by hand.

A good example of a type independent swap macro can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982430/5237890

Comment: Still won't change the output since i is not greater than j

Comment: This is true but questioner expected the values not to be swapped.

Comment: Just braces `{}` is not enough, because something like `if (x) swap(a,b); else something();` will not work. Basile's answer gives the trick that is commonly used to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should add curly braces to your macro declaration to solve your problem.

Moreover, if you want to **swap** basic type, like **int** for example, you can use the **XOR** operator to swap the values without use an additional variable.

```
#define swap(a, b) { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another problem is the line

```
if( i > j)
```

In your case, i=5 and j=10, so the first statement of the`swap()` line is not executed. As @Kninnug pointed out (almost), without curly braces your code is actually

```
if(i > j)
    temp = i;
i = j
j = temp;
```

Now, since I=5 and j=10, only the last two lines are executed, so I becomes 10 (the value of j) and j becomes zero (the value of temp).

Answer (score 0):

When using a function-like macro the compiler just replaces the text in the code where you call the function with the text in your macro declaration. You did not use curly braces after the if statement which would be fine if you only needed to execute one line of code. But when the compiler does the text replacement for your macro function, there are now three lines of code that need to be nested under the if statement.

Adding curly braces around the line `Swap ( a, b )` will fix your problem. Alternatively you can place curly braces around the three lines of code in your macro declaration.