# How do I make my code sort input in ascending order?

Tags: c

i want input randomly 3 number and then Ascending order output.
big one->small one
you know what i mean?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int a, b, c;
    int min, mid, max;


    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

    if (a > b) {
        max = a;
        min = b;
    }

    else {
        max = b;
        min = a;
    }

    mid = c;

    if (c > max) {
        max = c;
        mid = a > b ? a : b;
        min = a < b ? a : b;
    }

    else if (c < min) {

        min = c;
        mid = a < b ? : a : b;
            max = a > b ? : a : b;

    }

    printf("1:%d 2:%d 3:%d", max, mid, min);



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And please tell us what's wrong with the program. Do you get build errors? Crashes when running? Wrong results? If you get build errors, please copy-paste them into the question. For wrong results, please tell us the input you give, together with the actual and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is illogical and tangled up. The simplest way of sorting 3 numbers is to use `swap` three times:

```
if (a > c) swap(&a, &c);
if (a > b) swap(&a, &b);
if (b > c) swap(&b, &c);
```

Introducing new variables is not necessary, and I'm not convinced they are all set on every control path so that could produce undefined results. To build `swap`, see [Is there a built-in way to swap two variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637856/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-swap-two-variables-in-c), or use this one:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
   int t = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = t;
}
```

Finally, don't forget to check the return value of `scanf`; it should be 3 in your case.

Comment: @Dovnvoter, if I've slipped something then do please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand yet, but I appreciate your advice.