# Why value is changed after swap?

Tags: c

Why 10.5 become 10.0 after swap ?

```
#define swap(a,b) {int aux; aux=a; a=b; b=aux;}
float x=10.5, y=3.75;

swap(x,y);

// x=3.75, y=10.0;
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you called `swap(1.5,2.5)`?

Comment: change int aux to float aux. you are storing float value in int variable.

Comment: You may be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20380289/459640

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aux` is of type `int`, which will drop the decimal part of the argument `a` passed to `swap`. In this case, `swap(x, y)` drops the decimal part of `x` before it is assigned to `y` at the end.